# How to center ListView footer horizontally

Tags: android

I've added a footer to my ListView like so:

```
...{
  listView.addFooterView(getButtonFooter(context));
...}

    private View getButtonFooter(Context context) {
        Button button = new Button(context);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_reminder_btn_selector);
        button.setId(ADD_REMINDER);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        return button;
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can now center the button horizontally.

EDIT: oh, maybe like this? `button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

EDIT: lol, nope. That didn't seem to work. Guess that just center's the text inside the button...

Comment: center means what... you want it to be the middle element of listView..? or something else..

Comment: No, it's a footer so it's at the bottom of the ListView. I'd like to be centered horizontally in the layout, which happens to also be center horizontally in terms of the ListView.

Comment: you can do that using getCount() method of adapter.. but i'm not sure since the snippet you have posted is too small to conclude anything..

Comment: @ntc getCount() tells me how many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter. You're suggestion is what? At the end of the day AbsListView.LayoutParams doesn't have a method for setMargins or anything like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_reminder_btn_selector);
        button.setId(ADD_REMINDER);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        layout.addView(button);
        return layout;
```

Comment: Thanks Dharmendra. That worked. To be sure though, the LinearLayout needs AbsListView.LayoutParams since it's gonna be part of the ListView. Thanks!